# Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r

After transitioning my code from one computer to the next I keep encountering the error Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0.

Here is the code

```
library("nlmixr2")
data<- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Simcyp Simulator\\Downloads\\NHP Nonmem style file.csv")
nhp <- function() {
  ini({
    tcl <- 4.15
    tv <-  0.9  
    eta.cl + eta.v ~ c(1,
                       0.01, 1)
    add.err <- .0278    
  })
  model({
    cl <- exp(tcl + eta.cl)
    v <- exp(tv + eta.v)    
    ke <- cl /  v              
    d/dt(depot) = -ka * depot
    d/dt(center) = ka * depot - cl / v * center
    cp = center / v
    cp ~ add(add.err)      
  })
}

fit.nhp <- nlmixr2(nhp, data, est = "saem",control=list(print=0),
                   table=list(cwres=TRUE, npde=TRUE))
```

[image: The CSV File]
[image: Data when using dput(data)]

I have used different files with the same data and tried both csv and excel files. I also imported into R to try and directly use the data if it was read csv that was having the issue. This same code runs on a different computer without issue, so I am a bit lost for what could be the problem. As far as I am aware I have downloaded all the same packages in their most up to date forms on this computer as well.

Comment: does the error occurs when running the function or reading the file? could you provide the data.frame `data` with `dput(data)`or `dput(head(data)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added in a picture of what the data frame looks like as well as the csv file. Its large so I did not include the whole thing in the picture but it should be enough to get the picture.